# Cannot localize strings in Flutter TabBarView

Tags: flutter, localization

When I try to localize a string in a TabBarView I get this error:

NoSuchMethodError: The method 'translate' was called on null. Receiver: null. Tried calling: translate("username).

I use this line of code to translate a key to a localized string:

```
AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('username')
```

This works great in all the other screens of my app except this one. Does anyone know why it's not working and how to solve it?

Some things I already tried:

- pass the context of the main screen (the screen that holds all the TabBarViews)
- wrap every ListTile in a Builder
- wrap the ListView in a Builder

Code:

```
class AccountScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String username;
  final String email;
  final int points;

  AccountScreen(this.username, this.email, this.points);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('username')),
              subtitle: Text(username),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title:
                  Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('email_address')),
              subtitle: Text(email),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('points')),
              subtitle: Text('$points'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that there were multiple MaterialApp widgets inside the app that were causing some conflicts regarding the localisation process. Removing the Redundant MaterialApp widgets fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found same problem. But in my case is using `MaterialApp` without `localizationsDelegates`. (I mean all file not only `main.dart`).

So i add `localizationsDelegates` on every `MaterialApp` in all widget.

e.g.

```
   MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        MainLocalizationsDelegate.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            brightness: Brightness.light,
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(text: MainLocalizations.of(context).food),
                Tab(text: MainLocalizations.of(context).car),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              TabA(),
              TabB(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```